# VBA Getting Compile Error: Invalid use of new keyword

Tags: vba, excel

this code is use to convert PDF to excel.
But a problem was found during the compilation. The error message getting is "Compile Error: Invalid use of new keyword" at line "Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.CAcroHiliteList". I have no idea to fix this and had many try on this. I need some advise, guidance from you. Appreciated and Thank you.

```
Private Sub ABC()

   Dim AC_PD As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

   Dim AC_Hi As Acrobat.CAcroHiliteList

   Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

   Set AC_Hi = New Acrobat.CAcroHiliteList

   '...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by a cursory look at [the documentation](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_developer_guide.pdf), it looks like their COM interfaces might be a little jacked up. Try this instead:

```
Set AC_PD = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set AC_Hi = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
```

The typedef names are on page 19.